# What is the difference between a TabLayout and an AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been learning about tabs and ActionBar in Android. I can't get my head around it. what is the difference between a TabLayout and an AppBarLayout? why you put Toolbar tag inside AppBarLayout? what programmers want to achieve doing this?

the following xml file is an example from HeadFirst Android. if possible, consider answering my Qs by explaining what is happening here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AppBarLayout**

AppBarLayout is a `vertical LinearLayout` that is generally the first child inside a `CoordinatorLayout` and acts as a `wrapper` for the `ToolBar` in most cases. Using the `ToolBar` as a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` would work fine but it will not be able to coordinate with other child views present. Here’s where the importance of `AppBarLayout` arises. It allows it’s `child views` to achieve the desired `scrolling` behavior using the param `app:layout_scrollFlags`

**TabLayout**

TabLayout is another popular view type introduced in the Material Design Guidelines. It provides a `horizontal layout` to display `tabs` which are generally placed at the top of the screen according to the Android UI Guidelines.

For more info and example [see this](https://www.journaldev.com/12858/android-tablayout-appbarlayout)